# Ruby string conversion needed from one format to another needed by a solr query

Tags: ruby, string, solr

```
solr_query_string= '{!term f=f_type_of_work tag=item_type}Thesis", "{!term f=f_type_of_work tag=item_type}Dataset'
```

**How can I convert this string to look like:**

```
solr_query_string='f_type_of_work:(\"Thesis\") OR f_type_of_work:(\"Dataset\")'
```

"{!term f=f_type_of_work}" is a variant .

Its not always f_type_of_work.
Sometimes the string can contain more than one type of f , ex: f=f_type_of_funder

I want to be able to 'OR' only the like fields. ie:

```
solr_query_string= '{!term f=computed__contains_full_text}true","{!term f=f_type_of_work tag=item_type}Thesis", "{!term f=f_type_of_work tag=item_type}Dataset"'
```

**How can I convert this string to look like:**

```
solr_query_string='computed__contains_full_text:(\"true\")","f_type_of_work:(\"Thesis\") OR f_type_of_work:(\"Dataset\")'
```

Comment: What you show in your first line is not a string. Do you intend it to be surrounded by single quotes: `'solr_query_string= ["{!term...Dataset"]'`? If so, please edit to add the single quotes. Same for the other strings. I am not just being picky; your first line assigns a value to a local variable.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @cary-swoveland, corrected the strings.